# What does the abbreviation C.E. mean in a piece of text dated 1828?

Tags: abbreviations

The sentence in which it is used begins: -

> The theatre had been run up in seven months by Mr. Stedman Whitwell, C.E.,

and is found  [here](http://anengineersaspect.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/collapse-of-brunswick-theatre-february.html)

Comment: Apparently, the person's qualification/ designation, could be Civil Engineer/ Chief Engineer. However, that seems off topic on ELU. Voting to close.

Comment: Not quite about the English language and its usage.

Answer (score 2):

Given the nature of the blog, and a sentence like

> On this as on a previous occasion, Mr. Whitwell flew into a violent passion about the danger of the pendent and vibrating weight. He told Mr. Carruthers that he had first observed the strain on the roof on the 15th of February, while inspecting the ventilating apparatus,

it would indeed appear to mean *Civil Engineer*.

In fact, OED lists *Civil Engineer* before *Common/Christian Era:*

[image: Screenshot of online OED]

Comment: So be it - this is probably not the place for a dyspraxic and dyslexic secondary school reject like me, who lacks the discernment to post apposite questions in the "right" place.

delete away monitors.

I suspected Civil Engineer but wondered if that term was in such use as early as 1828.

sorry for being off topic.

Comment: Well, I disagree that it's off topic (but moderators do not generally overrule five community members). The question could have been improved by including your own research In other dictionaries  — OED isn't easily accessible, so it's a great answer resource.

Comment: I access OED as a member of Essex County Council Library, available on line without charge for any County resident.

I did not look up C.E. there on this occasion, I wanted the opinions of other researchers who perhaps had better historical awareness than me.

I presume this exchange will be removed or relocated as it is not about grammar.